# How to install a specific version of PostgreSQL in Red Hat 8?

Tags: redhat, postgresql, yum, rhel8, dnf

I'd like to install a specific version of PostgreSQL in RHEL 8 with dnf.
To achieve this I followed the PostgreSQL guide : https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

But actually I can only install the last version (12.9) not the 12.4 (the version I want).
The version is however present in the repository :

[image: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-8.5-x86_64/]

See : https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-8.5-x86_64/

If I list the versions available with dnf :

[image]

I can see only 12.9 is available.

But if I show duplicate packages, I can see the version 12.4 :

[image]

So is there a way to install this specific version, since it's present on the reposity ?

Comment: Have an specific reason for installl that version? Rember RHEL use the last updated version coz the last version are stable and bugs fixed

Comment: We want to freeze the version :
- to keep the same version for all our clients
- to prevent a change of behavior or a mandatory operation to do after update (like reindexing some indexes)

Answer (score 2):

If the package is in the repo you can detail the version like `<package-name>-<version>[.<architecture>]`.

So in this case:

```
dnf install postgresql12-server-12.4-4PGDG.rhel8
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always install any version directly from the sources (https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v12.4/ in your example).

Comment: I'd prefer not to install from source, for evident reasons

Comment: what is your 'evident' reason @mishka?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here. I need to install version 12.4 and then test the upgrade to 12.9.
you can install postgresql 12.4 from source (https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v12.4/) with 3 major steps:

1. wget source package and extract it
2. ./config > make > make install
3. add postgres user and initdb, and then start db
   I successfully installed postgresql 12.4, however, I had the problem to install extension(postgis)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend installing from AppStream:

```
yum module list postgresql

yum module install -y postgresql:{ver}

postgres --version
```

For more information, run through this online lab! https://lab.redhat.com/appstream-manage

Comment: That's not helping me, I still can't install version 12.4 with this (only 12.9 possible).

Comment: Is there something preventing you from upgrading your database to a newer version?